# SQL Server copy a column to a new one but with different string pattern

Tags: sql-server

I have a column in a table (`profiles`) called `profile_p` with 2399 records with the following string pattern

```
profile_p + 10 digit unique ID      (ex: profile_p1234567890)
```

Now what I want to do is:
create another new column inside this table and copy all these records BUT with the following
string pattern

```
profile_p_th + 10 digit unique ID     (ex: profile_p_th1234567890)
```

The id stays same what I want to change is `profile_p` to `profile_p_th`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you.

```
UPDATE profiles SET newcolumn=REPLACE(profile_p, 'profile_p', 'profile_p_th')
```

But why don't you just store the numerical string without this constant prefix?

Comment: OHHH my God worked like a charm! You are god - 54353452345234 years was trying to figure this out! Great question you asked these two columns are for image profile links for a site - the columh profile_p is for the initial photo and the profile_p_th the thumbnail of this - ID is the unique id of the user Thanks AGAIN!!!